# php: compiling with openssl, ftp, ldap, curl support in debian gnu/linux

Tags: php, ftp, ldap, openssl, curl

I'm trying to compile php 5.2.x in debian gnu/linux:

> ./configure --with-ldap --enable-ftp --with-apxs2 --with-mcrypt
>   --enable-bcmath --with-bz2 --enable-calendar --enable-dba=shared --enable-exif --with-gettext --enable-mbstring --with-mhash --with-readline --enable-shmop --enable-soap --enable-sockets --enable-sysvmsg --enable-wddx --enable-zip --with-zlib --with-xsl
>
> make

works perfect, but i need curl:

> ./configure --with-ldap --enable-ftp --with-apxs2 --with-mcrypt
>   --enable-bcmath --with-bz2 --enable-calendar --enable-dba=shared --enable-exif --with-gettext --enable-mbstring --with-mhash --with-readline --enable-shmop --enable-soap --enable-sockets --enable-sysvmsg --enable-wddx --enable-zip --with-zlib --with-xsl --with-curl
>
> make

error:

> /usr/bin/ld: ext/curl/.libs/interface.o: undefined reference to symbol
>   'CRYPTO_set_id_callback@@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
>   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0: error adding symbols:
>   DSO missing from command line collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit
>   status Makefile:241: recipe for target 'sapi/cli/php' failed

**dpkg -l | grep openssl**

> ii  libcurl4-openssl-dev:amd64            7.38.0-4+deb8u5
>   amd64        development files and documentation for libcurl (OpenSSL
>   flavour)
>
> ii  libgnutls-openssl27:amd64             3.3.8-6+deb8u3
>   amd64        GNU TLS library - OpenSSL wrapper
>
> ii  openssl                               1.0.1t-1+deb8u5
>   amd64        Secure Sockets Layer toolkit - cryptographic utility

**dpkg -l | grep curl**

> ii  curl                                  7.38.0-4+deb8u5
>   amd64        command line tool for transferring data with URL syntax
>
> ii  libcurl3:amd64                        7.38.0-4+deb8u5
>   amd64        easy-to-use client-side URL transfer library (OpenSSL
>   flavour)
>
> ii  libcurl3-gnutls:amd64                 7.38.0-4+deb8u5
>   amd64        easy-to-use client-side URL transfer library (GnuTLS
>   flavour)
>
> ii  libcurl4-openssl-dev:amd64            7.38.0-4+deb8u5
>   amd64        development files and documentation for libcurl (OpenSSL
>   flavour)

**UPDATE**: the error is about FTP with openssl support:

> ./configure --with-openssl --enable-ftp
>
> make

```
ext/openssl/openssl.o: In function `zm_startup_openssl':
/usr/src/php-5.2.17/ext/openssl/openssl.c:681: undefined reference to `SSL_library_init'
...
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:228: recipe for target 'sapi/cli/php' failed
make: *** [sapi/cli/php] Error 1
```

Comment: Did you install package `libssl1.0.0`? And what Debian version are you running?

Comment: PHP 5.2 is ancient and unsupported and should not be used at all anymore.

Comment: @Daniel yes, Michael Hampton there is same issue with php 5.6 branch, i think the problem is in openssl, i will update soon

Comment: Why would you want to install from source? I think it would be better to ask what is the original problem you are trying to solve, than for a fix in your solution.

Comment: @MirceaVutcovici some of my projects only works in php 5.2.x, anyway is interesting how to build it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was openssl, well, I installed openssl 0.9.8 from [source](https://www.openssl.org/source/old/0.9.x/openssl-0.9.8.tar.gz):

Move to `/usr/src` compile it, and install it without man pages due to an error:

> ./config --prefix=/usr/local/openssl --openssldir=/usr/local/openssl
>   no-asm -fPIC
>
> make
>
> make install_sw

Then i compile `php` with this options:

> ./configure --with-openssl=/usr/local/openssl
>   --with-openssl-dir=/usr/local/openssl --with-curl --enable-ftp --with-ldap --with-apxs2 --enable-bcmath --with-bz2 --enable-calendar --enable-exif --enable-mbstring --with-mhash --enable-shmop --enable-soap --enable-sockets --enable-sysvmsg --enable-zip --with-zlib
>
> make

**UPDATE:** works for 5.6.28 too